# pgRouting: unable to execute routing_core.sql

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I'm unable to execute the routing_core.sql, receiving following error.

I'm using pgAdmin III, Windows 7, PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 2.0.

ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/librouting.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
SQL state: 58P01

Regards,
Nas

Comment: I am using the exact same set up and have no problem.  Where did you get your binaries and .sql files from?  Are you sure it is the correct version of PostgreSQL 9.1 because the one on the PgRouting site will not work with v9.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, pgRouting Windows binary doesn't support PostgreSQL x64(**Win x86_64**) version.
If you want to run pgRouting on Windows 64-bit OS, install PostgreSQL x86(**Win x86_32**) version.
(And PostGIS 1.5.x may be better because of [assign_vertex_id - MULTILINESTRING issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/newbie-postgis-geometry-and-multilinestring-clarification).)

Comment: Doh! I forgot that I had installed the x32 version on my 64-bit windows 7 box for this very reason.  Sorry for being misleading in my comment.

Comment: after all, for pgRouting, i'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.4 and pgRouting 1.5. These two combinations work perfect. ;)

Comment: sorry for the super late response. ;)